# $watch is not trigger without a complete refresh

Tags: angularjs, watch

I have a $watch setup to monitor an array (menuItems) of values in a service (MenuFilter).

```
    $scope.filterMenuItems = MenuFilter.menuItems;

    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return MenuFilter.menuItems;
    }, function (newVal, oldVal) {

        if ( newVal !== oldVal ) {
            $scope.filterMenuItems = newVal;
        }
    });
```

At a certain moment a menu item is deleted and I expect the list to be updated by the watch but it isn't. It is only updated when I refresh the  page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to add `true` as the third parameter to make a deep watch or better use `$watchCollection`.

The issue is that `$watch` only uses reference comparison, i.e. it does not monitor items *inside* your array - only the array reference itself (`oldArray === newArray`).

Comment: I've already added the 'true' but doesn't help me out, though it looks triggered more regularly. 

How to use the $watchCollection in this case?

Comment: How does the menu item get deleted?

Comment: @Nicholas are you passing in true as string or bool?

Comment: the true is passed in as bool. It seems that when deleting or adding a menuItem there was no update triggered in the service. So I've added a trigger to update the array in the service after delete or add and now it works fine! @MichaelRose I'll mark your answer as correct as it was the most useful

Comment: That's what I wanted to ask with my question - whether the removal was done in an angular digest loop or outside ;)